# Should I put database and CMS files on a separate EBS or S3?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, backup

Is is possible, or even advisable to use and EBS instance that remains at Instance Termination, to store database/website files, and reattach to a new Amazon instance in case of failure? OR should I backup a volume-bundle to S3? Also, I need an application to accelerate terminal window functions intelligently.  Can you tell I'm a linux NOob?

Comment: Please clarify your question, it's very difficult to read. What you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

We do this with our Nexus installation - the data is stored on a separate EBS instance that's regularly snapshotted but the root disk isn't (since we can use Puppet to create a working Nexus instance using the latest base AMI, Java, Tomcat and Nexus versions). The one drawback of this approach (vs your other approach of backing up to S3) is that you can't retrieve it outside of AWS if needed - if that is an important use case I'd recommend either uploading a volume bundle or a .tar.gz backup to S3.

However, in your case if you have a single EBS-backed EC2 instance which is your CMS server you could run it with a large root volume and keep that regularly backed up (either using EBS Snapshots or backing up a .tar.gz to S3) - if you're not particularly familiar with Linux that'll likely be the easiest way to make sure all your data is backed up (and if you need to extract the data only you can always do this by attaching that volume (or an instantiation of a snapshot of it) to another machine - you'd also have access to all the config files which may be of use...

Bear in mind that if you only want to run your server some of the time you can always Stop the instance rather than Terminate it - the EBS Instances will remain. Once you take a snapshot your data is safe - if part of an EBS Instance fails but it hasn't been modified since the last snapshot then AWS will transparently restore it with the EBS Snapshot data.